# facing issue. lateinit property viewModelFactory has not been initialized

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mvvm, dagger-2

I am new in android kotlin and dagger,I am facing above issue. I already provide the ViewModelFactory but facing issue i don't know why this issue is came, i have attached the MainActivity, Repository class and Viewmodel class,Please resolve my issue what I am take my mistake, Please help.

//MainActivity.class

```
`class MainActivity  : AppCompatActivity() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory

    private lateinit var reportViewModel: ReportsViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //(application as PWEApplication).daggerComponent.inject(this)
        reportViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(ReportsViewModel::class.java)
        reportViewModel.report.observe(this, Observer {
            when(it.status){
                NetworkResource.Status.LOADING -> {
                    // Show a loading indicator
                }
                NetworkResource.Status.SUCCESS -> {
                    // Show the data from the API
                    Log.e("installationReport",""+it.data)
                }
                NetworkResource.Status.ERROR -> {
                    // Show an error message
                }
            }
        })
    }
}`
```

//Viewmodel.class

```
``open class ReportsViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: ReportsRepository) :ViewModel() {

    private var reportLiveData = MediatorLiveData<ReportRequest>()

    val report = Transformations.switchMap(reportLiveData) {
        repository.getReports(it)
    }

    fun getInstallReport(idd: Int, fromDate: String, toDate: String) {
        reportLiveData.value = ReportRequest(idd, fromDate, toDate)
    }

}`
```

//ReportRepository.class

```
class ReportsRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val reportServiceNS: ReportsService,
    private val schedulerProvider: SchedulerProvider
) {
    private val reportsMutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<NetworkResource<List<ResponseItem>>>()
    private var disposable: Disposable? = null

    fun getReports(reportRequest: ReportRequest): MutableLiveData<NetworkResource<List<ResponseItem>>>{
        disposable = reportServiceNS.getReport(
            reportRequest.script,
            reportRequest.deploy,
            reportRequest.compId,
            reportRequest.h,
            reportRequest.discId,
            reportRequest.fromDate,
            reportRequest.toDate)
            .compose(schedulerProvider.getSchedulersForObservable())
            .subscribeWith(object : DisposableObserver<ReportResponse>() {
                override fun onComplete() {

                }

                override fun onNext(t: ReportResponse) {
                    reportsMutableLiveData.value = NetworkResource.success(t.complaintData)
                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    reportsMutableLiveData.value = NetworkResource.error(e, null)
                }

            })

        return reportsMutableLiveData
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned you are using dagger. I see you are expecting the following to be injected, but doing nothing for that to happen:

```
    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory
```

So I can imagine your app is crashing because `viewModelFactory` is not initialized. Depending on your DI structure, you should either do component/subcomponent injection, or use `AndroidInjection.inject(this)`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to annotate the ViewModel with `@HiltViewModel` and the activity with `@AndroidEntryPoint`, then you can `import androidx.activity.viewModels` and then have

```
private val model: ReportsViewModel by viewModels()
```